# Is it possible to use Cognito Forms offline or some way to implement an offline solution?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to use [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) offline, or some way to implement an offline solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not have native support for offline use, but this is a feature on our Idea Board.

However, for those with programmer superpowers, here are a few suggestions and code snippets that can be used to implement your own solutions:

1. Use the seamless embed option, which makes the embedded form be part of
   your web page, enabling manipulation of the data and HTML via
   JavaScript and CSS.
2. You can obtain the JSON data for a form at any time using the
   following JavaScript:

   ```
   var json = Cognito.serialize(Cognito.Forms.model.entry);
   ```
3. You can prefill forms from JSON data using the following JavaScript:

   ```
   Cognito.deserialize(null, json, Cognito.Forms.model.entry);
   ```

These snippets will allow you to save and restore information for a Cognito Form, but significant additional programming is required to create offline solutions depending on your specific requirements.